# Does 'Other creatures you control have intimidate' affect new creatures brought out?

Tags: magic-the-gathering

[Bellowing Tanglewurm](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Bellowing%20Tanglewurm) and [Dwynen, Gilt-Leaf Daen](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Dwynen%2C%20Gilt-Leaf%20Daen) have abilities like

> Other green creatures you control [...]

and

> Other Elf creatures you control [...]

Do abilities like these only affect creatures that were already on the battlefield? Will creatures that enter the battlefield later also get the effect?

If the creature with the ability dies, will the effect remain on the creatures that had it?

Comment: Have you read through the Basic Rulebook for MTG? http://www.wizards.com/magic/rules/en_magic_basic_rulebook_20090710.pdf. Static abilities are described on page 11.

Comment: No I haven't, I was taught to player by a friend and everything else I've been learning by going through a set of cards I bought in bulk for really cheap, and asking questions here if I didn't understand something and could not find it by searching for the answer, I'll check that out, thanks!

Comment: Definitely nothing wrong with asking questions here; but I highly recommend the basic rules. And I also recommend NOT looking into the comprehensive rules (which is what I've quoted in my answer) much; they are not intended to be used to learn the game, and it wouldn't be helpful at all.

Comment: I'll be sure to read it so I will ask less obvious questions, I really appreciate your help, thank you I'm going to read it right now

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It will affect all your creatures for as long as you control it; whether those creatures were there when you first cast it or not. Your creatures will lose the bonus as soon as you stop controlling it. This is called a static ability, which generates a continuous effect. It's described in detail in this rule:

> 604.2. Static abilities create continuous effects, some of which are prevention effects or replacement effects. These effects are active as long as the permanent with the ability remains on the battlefield and has the ability, or as long as the object with the ability remains in the appropriate zone, as described in rule 112.6.

Comment: Note that the answer is different if *other green creatures you control* is part of a continuous effect created by something other than a static ability. For example, *When $this enters the battlefield, other green creatures you control get +1/+1 until the end of the turn.* doesn't affect green creatures that enter the battlefield after the ability resolves. See 611.2c

Comment: Yeah, I actually started off quoting the continuous effect rule instead, but I figured that the static abilities rule was better here because of that exact thing.